# Understanding how PHP file worked (auto-decode of query string?)

Tags: php

I am debugging a PHP file that I've never seen operational before (not my code), but supposedly worked.

Sample code snippet of `myfile.php`:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
<?
    echo $Year;
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

From the way things are wired, it looks like the code is setup to pull Year from the query string (HTTP GET): http://server.com/myfile.php?Year=2010

This supposedly worked before, but doesn't anymore.

Is there a PHP setting to control this?  Was this a 'feature' that got disabled in PHP version?  I have never seen GET variables used outside of `$_GET`

Comment: Correct, this was a "feature". It's no longer with us, thank goodness. http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like to previous server was set with register global **on**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals

http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

**Note:** This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Instead of altering the servers config to support a deprecated and unsafe feature, fix your code by accessing the `$_GET` global:

```
<?php 
$Year = isset($_GET['Year']) ? $_GET['Year'] : null;
?>

<html>
<body>
<p>
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars($Year);
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you - I don't use PHP from day-to-day so I didn't know what this was called.  I will mark as Answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

The PHP directive `register_globals` would turn on/off a facility to  decode the query string into global variables of the same name automatically. This was, in many people's opinions, a dreadful idea, since variables could appear with no obvious origin or value.

It once defaulted to `on`, but was changed to `off` in PHP 4.2. You could still enable it in PHP.INI. It's been deprecated as of PHP5.3, and removed in PHP 5.4.

If your code was working but is not now, look for a change in version (to PHP 5.4), or check what's in php.ini.

In any case, if you're looking at the code, now might be a good time to change to references to `$_GET`, and disable `register_globals`